# NodeJs Executing code from attached process

Tags: node.js, debugging

I'm trying to trigger a function that lives in my application by attaching to the running process using the `node inspect -p <PID>`. The function is being imported in the `server.js` however when I attach to the running process and try to call the function I get an `Uncaught ReferenceError: is not defined`.

Is there a way to call a function by attaching to a running process?